# How to show hidden div in the same line as the paragraph text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the [mentions plugin](https://github.com/CogniStreamer/tinyMCE-mention) to add a hidden user id so I can parse the user correctly.

When I mention someone here is how it needs to look like

```
Hello [Mention User], This is just a test
```

to do that, I had to override the `insert` method within the plugin like this

```
    insert: function(data){
        return   '<div style="display: inline;">'
                    + '<span class="mentionedUser">[' + data.name + ']</span><div class="hiddenMentionUserID" style="display:none;">'+data.id+'</div>'
               + '</div>';
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that is does not show the text on the same line as I am expecting.

Rather, here is how is the text being displayed

```
Hello
[Mention User]
, This is just a test
```

How can I tweak my html/css code to make the mention name appears on the same line as the text along with the hidden user id?

Comment: can you step through to see what the `data` object is at return time ? any console errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use div use a span

```
 insert: function(data){
        return   '<span >'
                    + '<span class="mentionedUser">[' + data.name + ']</span><div class="hiddenMentionUserID" style="display:none;">'+data.id+'</div>'
               + '</span>';
    }
```

Comment: this is closer... but now I see the text after the hidden div under new line. can I create a hidden span rather than hidden div?

Comment: Yes you can, or in the second div  put style="display: inline, like you are doing in the first div

Comment: I need the user ID to be hidden. How can I make a hidden span?

Comment: With style="display:none;"  you can hide whatever you want

Comment: aha,,, thank you.. I did not know I can hide a span :)  I will accept your answer in 3 minutes :)